# I can't get the jQuery animation to work with my js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've never used jQuery before. I probably messed something up with it. The js is working fine to hide / show the menu. The animation isn't doing anything tho.

Here is my js:

```
//show / hide menu on mobile
mobileMenuButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  $('mainMenu').slideToggle(200)
  if (mainMenu.style.display !== "none") {
    mainMenu.style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    mainMenu.style.display = "flex";
  }

})
```

This is at the top of my js:

```
//jQuery???
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you provide a little more of the code? Possibly a [Code Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? Also I would suggest not using a mix of both vanilla JavaScript selectors and listeners combined with jQuery. Instead, look into how you use just jQuery -- like instead of `mobileMenuButton.addEventListener("click",  function() {});` you could have `$(mobileMenuButton).click(function() {});`

Comment: I agree with above comment. Also look into [.css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/), that could help!

Answer (score 0):

If you define `display: flex` within your CSS stylesheet then you do not need to specify it in your javascript. To hide your menu you can use an inline style of `display: none` on load, as this will be overridden by the `slideToggle()` function. This will really simplify your code.

A working example is shown below, I've added some basic structure and styling to the demo to help.

---

**DEMO**

```js
// Add click event listener
$("#mobileMenuButton").click(function() {

  // Slide toggle
  $('#mainMenu').slideToggle(200);
  
})
```

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  padding: 12px;
}

#mainMenu {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 12px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="navbar">
  <button id="mobileMenuButton">Mobile Menu</button>
</div>

<div id="mainMenu" style="display:none;">
  <li>Menu item</li>
  <li>Menu item</li>
  <li>Menu item</li>
</div>
```